# Where to convert? Please help

Tags: halacha, gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, synagogue, orthodox

My name is Caleb and I am a former Celtic Pagan who wishes to convert to Orthodox Judaism. I want to convert more than anything. My soul yearns for it. I'm not content being a Noahide, and even though I know that converts aren't true Jews, most Born Jews will not want anything to do with me, and I don't deserve to be Jewish, I love Judaism so much that I'm willing to move anywhere to accomplish a conversion. I live in far northeastern Maine and in my process of attempting to find a place to convert, I've tried to contact dozens of shuls, to no avail. In fact, I've faced mostly no responses, blatant rejection, or no help at all. I need to find a community and Rabbi who can help me on this journey. Can anyone help me? I'm losing hope day by day, and even though I trust HaShem will provide a place for me to accomplish this, so far I can't find one anywhere. Does anyone know any halachically kosher Orthodox shuls that help in conversions? Maybe even one backed by the RCA? I want to do this right, and at least find solice in my soul knowing I'm the closest thing to a Jew I could get.

Comment: You may want to check out https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12648/759

Comment: Converts are completely True Jews (tm). You won't be able to halachically marry a Kohain, but assuming you are male (as your username would indicate), that door was closed to you anyway.  http://judaismconversion.org/geirus-policies-and-standards/  is the place to get started. Good luck on your spiritual journey!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the beit din in Boston(https://www.sephardicboston.com/ask-the-rabbi.html)?