# Can I become Jewish just by saying “I am a Jew”?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I am interested in the faith of Judaism. I am curious about being “informally Jewish”. This is because I am interested in this religion because of its history and willingness to be open. I am not willing to be completely kosher (I mean this in the sense of not eating pork), but I want to call myself Jewish and be a Jew. Is that sufficient?

Comment: If you're not interesting in keeping all of Judaism, perhaps you would be interested in Noahidism - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahidism, https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-modern-noahide-movement/, etc.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52891/170

Comment: @Heshy No - this is asking on the conversion process. Do we have a question about what counts for conversion? Because that thread doesn’t seem to address that.

Comment: The answer to this question is definitely no. See [First steps for someone considering conversion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12648/first-steps-for-someone-considering-conversion) Look up the Rabbinical Council of America if you are really interested in conversion.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not sufficient to simply call yourself a Jew without certain procedures. You must undergo a conversion practice as explained by the rabbis. However, you can remain a non-Jew by being a Noahide and keeping the Seven Laws of Noah Commandments. However, if a gentile converts, he keeps the same Torah as a Jew. Thus, whether Jew or gentile; all people are created equal.